# excel calculate working days between dates gives #value error

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate working days between two dates but it give #Value error.
I used formula

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H3,J3,1)
```

**H3** cell has `16/11/2016 10:44:31` and **J3** cell has `11/25/2016  1:37:56 PM`. I have tried formatting **H3** cell as per **J3** to show AM/PM but its not changing.

Comment: Check your input... H3 has `16/11/2016` meaning that the format is `dd/mm/yyyy` while J3 has `11/25/2016` meaning that the format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have tried ISNUMBER and the H3 shows False. Also I have changed the date format from format cells to dd\mm\YYY but its not changing. Can you advise how can I make both format consistent

Comment: The fact that H3 is not a number means that Excel is interpreting it as a string. When you click on that cell, check if there is a single-quote at the left, something like `'16/11/2016 10:44:31`. If there is, it is a string. You would need to remove the single-quote, and then re-format the cell (or J3 for that matter) to be consistent in both cells.

Comment: By the way, as CallumDA33 implies, if the cell is left-aligned **without you setting such alignment**, it means that Excel sees it as a string (number and dates are right-aligned by default).

Answer (score 0):

As per FDavidov's comment, one of your dates are in the wrong format.

If your system date is in UK format, `dd/mm/yyyy`, then it's the date in **J3** that needs changing, otherwise it's **H3** that needs to be changed.

Dates should be right aligned in Excel (providing you haven't overridden that) so you should be able to quickly see which date is incorrect. Alternatively you can use `ISNUMBER(H3)` and `ISNUMBER(J3)` to test which is `FALSE` - this one needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have tried ISNUMBER and the H3 shows False. Also I have change the date format from format cells to dd\mm\YYY but the its not changing. Can you advise how can I make both format consistent

Comment: It won't change because excel can only format numbers as dates. You need to change **H3** to `11/16/2016 10:44:31` (by typing it in manually)